# Change Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS

Tags: upgrade

I've upgraded my LTS version of Ubuntu to Ubuntu 17.04 and from the day I've upgraded I've been struggling to get this thing stable. Sometimes my Wifi adapter doesn't work properly and sometimes I can't even copy things properly.

So I want to revert back to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Is there any way to get this done?

Comment: @M.Becerra no it's not a duplicate because I'm moving from latest version of ubuntu normal release to latest LTS release....

Comment: If you don't want to see it as a duplicate, don't, but it is, and the **accepted answer still can help you**, which I assume is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best way is to re-install Ubuntu, so that you have a clean installation, without conflicts.

You need to have an installation [CD/DVD/USB of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS](https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu).

- Then backup your relevant files, just copy them to an external drive
  or a secondary partition.
- Then run the installation CD/DVD/USB.
- On the installation select "Erase Ubuntu xx.xx and reinstall"

For more info check:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu